# How can I turn a set of set of integers into 3D vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, vector, set

I have a data matrix in an array of `data[12][51]` which is a 12 by 51 matrix.

If I have `set<set<int>> rows` as, for example,

`{(1,2,5),(3,7,8),(9,11)}` would denote rows indices of the data matrix.

I want to form matrices given those sets of rows indices, so the element of (1,2,5) would be a 3 by 51 matrix comprised by 1st, 2nd, and 5th rows of the data matrix.

```
vector<double> features[12];
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 51; j++){
        features[i].push_back(data[i][j]);
    }
}
```

So in the above section, `features[i]` would return an entire `i`'th row of the data matrix. And given an arbitrarily sized `set<set<int>> rows`,

```
vector<vector<vector<double>>> sets;
for (auto & it : rows){
    vector<vector<double>> temp;
    for (int i : it){
        temp.push_back(features[i]);
    }
    sets.push_back(temp);
}
```

But when I try to print such vector of matrices, via,

```
for (int i = 0; i < sets.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < sets[0].size(); j++){
        for (int z = 0; z < sets[0][0].size(); z++){
            cout << sets[i][j][z] << " , ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << " === Matrix === " << endl;
}
```

The executable freezes and just stops.

So, if the above method shouldn't be working, then how can I turn a set of set of integers into 3D vectors?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What's wrong with this question? Looks fine to me.

Comment: @Clonkex Is that providing a [MCVE] you can use to reproduce the described behavior?

Comment: _`sets[0].size();`_ should be `sets[i].size();` and _`sets[0][0].size()`_ should be `sets[i][j].size()`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, however it would probably be more helpful if you said exactly what was wrong with the question instead of just implying _something_ was wrong. The OP isn't going to automatically know what's wrong with the question. Plus it's pretty common for SO questions to not provide an MCVE, and they're not _required_, only recommended. Sometimes it's not possible to provide an MCVE, but it can still be a good question. Not trying to say you were wrong per se, but just saying it would have been helpful to mention what the OP should change.

Comment: @Clonkex Oh boy. My keyboard is working on a sparse number of electrons. That's why I gave them a link to the help center. I suppose they are at least able to read themselves.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ lol ok, well fair enough. If you'd linked the MCVE page instead I would have just upvoted your comment instead of ranting at you :P

Comment: I think std::vector<std::vector<double>> would be a better choice than std::set ...  std::set sorts its contents, and only keeps unique values.

Comment: The prior algorithm chose, due to its ability to sort only the unique values, the set of set of integers, but even after successfully converting std::set<std::set<int>> into std::vector<std::vector<int>> and used sets[i].size() , sets[i][j].size() as recommended above, the executable still freezes and stops working.

Comment: It's also handy if you know the size ahead of time to call `reserve`. Completely unrelated, but vectors are pretty inefficient if they have to keep attempting to reallocate memory.

Comment: @user355843 The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It's always nice to have a ready-made, all-purpose dynamically sized matrix in one's toolbox...  It'even nicer when you don't have to link in a library, and can pop it in any project at anytime. I'm sure there are thousands of them out there.

Add toppings as needed, and keep the all-dressed file in a safe place.

Things you could add: Get a submatrix, addition, etc.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
private:
  typedef std::vector<std::vector<T>> _Mat;

  _Mat matrix_;

public:
  Matrix(int rows, int cols)
  {
     matrix_.resize(rows);
     for (auto& v : matrix_)
     {
       v.resize(cols);
     } 
  }

  Matrix(int rows, int cols, const T* data)
  {
     matrix_.resize(rows);
     for (auto& v : matrix_)
     {
       v = std::vector<T>(data, data + cols);
       data += cols;
     } 
  }

  size_t rowCount() const  
  { 
    return matrix_.size(); 
  }

  size_t colCount() const  
  { 
    return (rowCount()) ? matrix_[0].size() : 0; 
  }

  const std::vector<T>& getRow(int n) const
  {
    return matrix_.at(n);
  }

  void setRow(int row, const std::vector<T>& v)
  {
    if (row >= rowCount() || v.size() != colCount())
    {
      throw std::exception(); // choose your favorite exception class
    }
    matrix_.at(row) = v;
  }

  std::vector<T> getCol(int col)
  {
    std::vector<T> result;
    std::for_each(matrix_.begin(), matrix_.end(), 
      [&](std::vector<T>& r)
      {
        result.push_back(r.at(col));
      });
    return result;
  }

  void setCol(size_t col, const std::vector<T>& v)
  {
    if (col >= colCount() || v.size() != rowCount())
    {
      throw std::exception(); // choose your favorite exception class
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < matrix_.size(); ++i)
    {
      matrix_[i][col] = v[i];
    }
  }

  std::vector<T>& operator[](size_t row) 
  { 
    return matrix_.at(row); 
  }

  const std::vector<T>& operator[](size_t row) const 
  { 
    return matrix_.at(row);
  }
};


int main()
{

   Matrix<double> a(12, 51);
   Matrix<double> b(3, 51);
   Matrix<double> c(12, 2);

   b.setRow(0, a.getRow(1));
   b.setRow(1, a.getRow(25));
   b.setRow(2, a.getRow(12));

   Matrix<double> c(12, 2);
   c.setCol(0, a.getRow(3));
   c.setCol(1, a.getCol(4));  // <<  throws!!

   std::vector<Matrix<double>> matrices;
   matrices.push_back(a);
   matrices.push_back(b);
   matrices.push_back(c);

   Matrix<std::vector<double>> matrixOfVectors;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

why not to use style like this:

```
int nMatrix[rowSize][volumnSize][deepSize] = { 0 };
```

Actually, we usually use array to operate 3D data

Comment: This should have been a comment, and _"Actually, we usually use array to operate 3D data"_ nope, we don't do so in standard c++.

Comment: Thank you for re-edit the answer of mine. Pretty new here, so a little strange to use it.  And a little weak on Cpp skills. Because I used vtkMatrix4x4 class in VTK developed by c++,which use the matrix like this... I'll check how standard c++ oprate this kind data. Sincerely thanks again.